# Pyqt QMdiSubWindow resize with variable number of widgets

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an QMdiSubWindow which contains a couple of widgets. One of these widgets is a QWidget with a QGridLayout() which can contain an arbitrary number of sub-widgets which is determined at runtime (initially none). I can't seem to workout how to get the MDISubWindow to automatically resize when the number of sub-widgets in the grid layout changes.  Should I be re-implementing the `sizeHint()` somewhere? ie in the main widget or the sub-widgets?

The QMdiSubWindow resizes fine when I drag the resize handle with the mouse and snaps to show the correct size.

I've tried calling `.resize()` and `.updateGeometry()` on both the widget and the QMdiSubWindow but It doesn't obviously work. Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as i know QGridLayout is not a QWidget descendant, so I have a feeling you could be calling .resize and update on the wrong object.

Comment: I actually meant that I was calling .resize etc on a QWidget with QGridLayout layout. I've updated to make this clearer.

Comment: @mor22. Have you tried [adjustSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ekhumoro suggested I try `adjustSize()`, which didn't work initially. I did some more searching and ended up with the following solution which worked for me

```
QTimer.singleShot(1, self.parent.windows[self.uuid].adjustSize)
```

where

```
self.parent.windows[self.uuid]
```

is the `QMdiSubWindow` object.  I'm guessing that just calling `self.adjustSize()` doesn't work because the `sizeHint` is not updated until the later in the event queue.